# What is marglist?

Tags: lists

It's used e.g. in the [documentation for biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc) to produce a nice list with the entry keys aligned to the left, in the margin.

```
\begin{marglist}
\item[\etex]
The \biblatex package requires \etex.
...
\end{marglist}
```

Alternatively, how do I typeset such a list, a dictionary or a glossary-like, I'm not even sure how I should call it, but take a look at the biblatex.pdf at the link above, or at microtype.pdf for another example.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide a page of the PDF, where we can see a marglist?

Comment: It is defined in `ltxdockit.sty`. But you can do it with enumitem too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible definition with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hologo}
\newcommand{\etex}{\hologo{eTeX}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{marglist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[marglist]{leftmargin=0pt,font=\bfseries\sffamily\color{SteelBlue!75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{marglist}
  \item[\etex]
  The biblatex package requires \etex.
  ...
  \item[\LaTeXe]
  The biblatex package requires \etex.
\end{marglist}

\end{document}
```

[image]